# Is.Obtuse triangle function/algorithm

Tags: computational-geometry

I am trying to compute a function (in R although what I am looking for is the algorithm) that:

> Given **3** points in the plane return a **1** if the triangle formed by these 3 points is obtuse and **0** in other case.

I'd rather prefer not to use the pythagorean theorem classification of triangles neither having to compute the three angles of the triangle and looking for the obtuse one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The simplest would be either to compute the angles or to compute $a^2,b^2,c^2$ and check $a^2>b^2+c^2$ and the other two. You want neither, but what do you expect?

Comment: That's what I want to avoid. Thanks anyway. I'm trying maybe to get it using a single angle and the opposite side, even a simplest way. I don't know if this would be possible at all.

Comment: What are you ready to accept then? Note that if it's only a question of speed, R computes in a vectorized way (can be fast), and if it's not enough it's easy to link a C or Fortran function.

Comment: You could also compute the dot product $\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{AC}$ and the other two. If one is negative (or equivalently if the product is negative), the triangle is obtuse. Likely not much faster than the pythagorean method, as there are $6$ multiplications for both.

Comment: But then I would need to compute all three dot products, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but you can't do much better I think.

Comment: Alright, I'll try, thanks